# osx - gitolite: login with git user from terminal

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I have gitolite running on my OSX Snow Leopard server, with my git user and all is going right.
I have a web server here so I need to pull from the server itself and I have no problem doing it from the server.

But what I want to do is to be able to login with that user using SSH from my workstation, but in my terminal doing `ssh git@myserver` results in this cryptic message:

> PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

so the question is: how can I pull remotely my files to update my staging server?

Thanks to all. I've googled for it and searched on stack overflow but found no answer

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in gitolite to login as git user through ssh.
Default behavior is showing you information about available repositories.

In your case gitolite can't show this information because of an issue mentioned here: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/report-output.mkd

> ## openssh5.6 side note: openssh 5.6
>
> It used to be that the gitolite documentation would say "just use ssh
> git@server" in the past, because gitolite defaults to the "info"
> command if no command is passed.
>
> However, starting with openssh 5.6, this won't work. The ssh client
> will now "Kill channel when pty allocation requests fail". This means
> that gitolite is not even invoked; you only get a message about pty
> allocation failure, followed by "connection closed".
>
> So now you have to use an explicit "info" command, (ssh git@server
> info) or add the -T option to ssh (ssh -T git@server).

If all the setting of gitolite were done right you are be able to push and pull data to the server without direct using *ssh* command.

Comment: thanks vedi for your response. anyway there is something i don't understand.. you're saying "If all the setting of gitolite were done right you are be able to push and pull data to the server without direct using ssh command."

if not using ssh command... how? (using -T option only show infos)

Answer (score 0):

I would [add the server as user in gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668674/ading-users-to-gitolite), and given you have everything setup correctly in gitolite you will be able to clone your repository using:

`git clone git@your-servers-hostname:repository-name`

git will connect using a ssh tunnel I think, which is why standard SSH login is disabled for the git user.

Comment: sorry this does not answer the question and nor is what i asked.

Comment: I apologize, I must have misunderstood something. Aren't you trying to pull a revision from you git repository onto you staging server?

Comment: Hi Simon
yes, but i'm trying to do it from my computer, in order to be able to update the staging even if i'm out of office and I haven't access to the server.
The user which gitolite runs is "git" so i wanna be able to do a sort of ssh git@myserver from my local machine, but it seems not to be possible

Comment: Yes, I believe that is impossible since gitolite disables SSH login. But since you have SSH access, why not just setup another account and do something like `git clone git@localhost:repo` or `git clone file:////Users/git/repositories/repo` (described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520121/222245))? I am running the exact same setup on OS X Lion Server and both of these worked, needed sudo for the `file` protocol one though.